# SQL between with nullable min and max value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with following columns.

| id | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | -101 |
| 2 | -100 | 100 |
| 3 | 101 | 200 |
| ... |  |  |
| 99 | 1000 | null |

I want to be able to find the record based on a value parameter where min <= value and value >= max.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table t
WHERE min <= some_value and some_value <= max
```

The problem is that the lowest and the highest record have no upper or lower bound.

My question is what is the best practice for these cases?

- Another table design?
- Put Integer.MIN and Integer.MAX for the null values?
- Maybe there is a query that can be used that can handle these null
  values?

Comment: Please add the expected result to your question. It seems that you would need to enhance your `WHERE` condition with `IS NULL OR` boolean constructs.

Comment: You could give your min and max an upper and lower bound like `WHERE COALESCE(min, -9999999) <= some_value AND some_value <= COALESCE(max, 9999999)` (as an option)

Comment: That was something in the lines of what I thought, but by just replacing the null upper and lower bound in the records themselves instead of using COALESCE function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ranges:

```
WHERE int4range(min, max, '[]') @> some_value
```

A GiST index can make this query fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) built into PostgreSQL to handle this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table t
 WHERE int8range(min, max, '[]') @> somevalue;
```

The `'[]'` argument makes the min and max values inclusive, and a null for either min or max makes the range unbounded on that side.

Comment: You mean `'[]'` as third argument, right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  You are right.  Sorry for my mistake.